# mongo-go-driver context wrapper functions

Tags: mongodb, go

All of the mongo-go-driver's database query methods accept a context:

```
func (coll *Collection) Find(ctx context.Context, ...)
```

It is common pass a child of an http request context with a timeout to these query methods:

```
ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(request.Context()), 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()
cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, ...)
```

This creates a lot of boilerplate within a web application's codebase. I was thinking of creating wrapper functions that create the context internally:

```
func (db *Database) FindWithContext(filter interface{}) error {
  ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
  defer cancel()  
  return db.Collection.Find(ctx, filter)
}
```

Is this a bad practice? Is the context supposed a child of an http request so that the timeout and cancellation is scoped within the handler? Would creating wrapper functions defeat the whole purpose of the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that works for you I see no issue with doing what you are suggesting. The Go driver is generally verbose to use.

Note that most drivers do not specify a timeout for each operation the way Go driver suggests using it.

You may consider setting socket timeout via the URI options, which can be done once for the entire program but isn't quite the same thing as a per-operation timeout.

Note also there are efforts under way to improve the per-operation timeout handling in drivers in general.